# Google App Engine: request.BasicAuth undefined (type *http.Request has no field or method BasicAuth)

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to deploy a go app to Google App Engine but compilation is failing because of this error.

```
request.BasicAuth undefined (type *http.Request has no field or method BasicAuth)
```

I figured this error meant that my google app engine installation was not the latest one so I updated it and now running `go_appengine/goapp version` returns:

`go version go1.4.1 (appengine-1.9.18) darwin/amd64`

I can successfully `serve` my app but I keep getting this error when I try to `deploy`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go AppEngine runtime environment uses Go version 1.2 as you can read it on the [Go Runtime Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/#Go_Introduction) page.

A beta version of 1.4 runtime version is available, you can read more about it here:

[**go1.4beta is now ready for testing**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/ndtQokV3oFo)

If you want to use the 1.4 beta runtime, you have to specify it in your `app.yaml` config file like this:

```
api_version: go1.4beta
```

Note that even though Go 1.4 is out (current version is 1.4.2), the AppEngine runtime version of 1.4 is still not released.

Quoting the relevant part:

> Go 1.4 has not yet been released, so the go1.4beta runtime is built 
>   from the release-branch.go1.4 of the core Go tree, and may be updated 
>   as Go 1.4 approaches.
>
> We will not be providing a beta version of the Go 1.4 SDK. You should 
>   use goapp deploy (or appcfg.py) from the normal Go App Engine SDK to 
>   deploy your app.
>
> To use go1.4beta, update your app.yaml file to use the new api_version:
>
> ```
> api_version: go1.4beta
> ```
>
> After Go 1.4 is released it will become the basis for api_version 
>   'go1', as normal, and 'go1.4beta' will be retired soon afterward. We 
>   expect this to happen early next year.